# CentOS(6.3) Gnome Desktop Environment does not respond!

Tags: centos, gnome

After starting the Gnome desktop on CentOS (version 6.3), I was able to see everything (the desktop icons, time and date, the upper titles for Applications, system, and so on). But, when I try to click on any of them, there is no response! The mouse pointer just blinks and changes as if something is going to open, but nothing happens—everything remains as it is.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: welcome to Stack Exchange! @Barun didn't mention it in his edit summary, but your thanks was removed because we prefer not to have extra fluff in questions. instead, you should show your thanks by upvoting and accepting answers.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, if the display manager is not responding, you should check it's related processes by using `ps` in a terminal.

You can usually do so by pressing `<CTRL> + <ALT> + <F1>` and logging in with your user.

In CentOS, you have 7 ttys available, with 7 being reserved for display manager.
This means `<CTRL> + <ALT> + <F1>` through `<CTRL> + <ALT> + <F6>` are for terminal use only.

Running only a teminal window gives you the benefit of:

1. Not running any GUI (therefore potentially bypassing its problems)
2. Checking to see if the system is responsive
3. Running diagnostic commands and getting statistics about the system

Once you have logged in, run `ps -eaf` and check for your display manager.

If it is there and continues to be unresponsive, you can `kill` it.

Keep in mind, any unsaved work in the GUI will be lost.